# How to know what variant expl3 functions to provide in a package?

Tags: expl3, expansion, best-practices, package-writing

This question stems from a [bug report](https://github.com/dcpurton/pdfoverlay/issues/4) to my package, [`pdfoverlay`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfoverlay).

The function in question is:

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pdfoverlay_set_pdf:n
  {
    \file_if_exist:nTF { #1 }
      {
        \str_gset:Nn \g__pdfoverlay_pdf_file_name_str { #1 }
        \__pdfoverlay_count_pdf_pages:
        \int_gzero:N \g__pdfoverlay_page_int
        \bool_gset_true:N \g__pdfoverlay_output_active_bool
        \bool_gset_false:N \g__pdfoverlay_action_pending_bool
      }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { pdfoverlay } { file-not-found } { #1 }
      }
  }
```

This works fine provided you pass a PDF filename directly to the macro. But if you store the PDF filename in a macro, it fails, because `str_gset:Nn` just detokenizes the control sequence.

Generating variants of `\pdfoverlay_set_pdf:n` (e.g., `V` or `o` or `x`) works around this.

### Questions

1. Should a style file provide these variants in this kind of case? Or Should they be left for a user to generate if they need them?
2. There's a LaTeX interface (`\pdfoverlaySetPDF`) which calls `\pdfoverlay_set_pdf:n`. There always seems to be risks (which I don't adequately understand) in forcing things to expand. But would there be a problem with creating a variety of variants and then calling `\pdfoverlay_set_pdf:x` from the LaTeX interface?

Comment: If you plan to allow users to store file names in (simple) macros, you should define the variant `\pdfoverlay_set_pdf:e` and call this one in the user level command.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Why is the `e` variant better than `x` in this case?

Comment: Because it's there… ;-) It does the same as `x`, but in a single step.

Comment: @egreg. Ha. That's why the next time I try something with expansion, someone will say: "You must never do this because it will break when that happens."

Comment: There is a small difference in `x` and `e`: in `e` you can use `#` without "escaping" it with a second `#` whereas with `x` you'd have to input `##` for a single `#`. The behaviour of `e` seems more reasonable for a string interface and filenames. And as the comment by @egreg already hints: It's faster (on modern/up to date engines, in pdfTeX and XeTeX before 2019, iirc, the `e` type is slower because it gets emulated).

Comment: are you sure that you need to `_str` the filename at all? (If you pre-expand with e or x it probably breaks utf8 filenames in pdftex where you need the active characters to expand correctly in a filename context) (this may change at the next latex dev release)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, no I am not at all sure that I need to `_str` the filename. (This is the 'expanding breaks here' comment I was waiting for.) Ultimately it gets passed to `\includegraphics`. It's also used by `\XeTeXpdfpagecount`, `\pdfximage` and `\saveimageresource`.  Is it best to store the filename in a token list and then perhaps I don't need to worry about expanding anything as the other lower level functions will take care of things for me?

Comment: certainly includegraphics will handle this id have to check the others